# How to pass multiple data in kafka producer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, distributed-computing, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Need to pass multiple data(object) along with file data,

Is there any serializer available to pass object or any ways?

Here is the code that just pass file data,

```
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9093");

        props.put("producer.type", "async");
        props.put("batch.size", "500");
        props.put("compression.codec", "1");
        props.put("compression.topic", "WRA");
        // props.put("key.serializer",
        // "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");

        org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer<Integer, byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<Integer, byte[]>(
                props);

        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<Integer, byte[]>("topic1", file.getBytes()));
```

Comment: Checkout this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112201/is-it-possible-to-transfer-files-using-kafka/39129352#39129352 , It tells about how to use MapSerializer with kafka.

Comment: @Rambler, Need to pass data along with file. Not only data

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40158971/2229409 answer, you can implement your own value serializer for an object including metadata and your file.