# How to create Custom serializer in kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

There is only few serializer available like,

```
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

How can we create our own custom serializer ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you have an example to use your own serializer/deserializer for the Kafka message value. For Kafka message key is the same thing.

We want to send a serialized version of MyMessage as Kafka value and deserialize it again into a MyMessage object at consumer side.

Serializing MyMessage in producer side.

You should create a serializer class that implements org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer

*serialize()* method do the work, receiving your object and returning a serialized version as bytes array.

```
public class MyValueSerializer implements Serializer<MyMessage>
{
    private boolean isKey;

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey)
    {
        this.isKey = isKey;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, MyMessage message)
    {
        if (message == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {

            (serialize your MyMessage object into bytes)

            return bytes;

        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error serializing value", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {

    }
}

final IntegerSerializer keySerializer = new IntegerSerializer();
final MyValueSerializer myValueSerializer = new MyValueSerializer();
final KafkaProducer<Integer, MyMessage> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props, keySerializer, myValueSerializer);

int messageNo = 1;
int kafkaKey = messageNo;
MyMessage kafkaValue = new MyMessage();
ProducerRecord producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, kafkaKey, kafkaValue);
producer.send(producerRecord, new DemoCallBack(logTag, startTime, messageNo, strValue));
```

Deserializing MyMessage in consumer side.

You should create a deserializer class that implements org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer

*deserialize()* method do the work, receiving serialized value as bytes array and returning your object.

```
public class MyValueDeserializer implements Deserializer<MyMessage>
{
    private boolean isKey;

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey)
    {
        this.isKey = isKey;
    }

    @Override
    public MyMessage deserialize(String s, byte[] value)
    {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {

            (deserialize value into your MyMessage object)

            MyMessage message = new MyMessage();
            return message;

        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error deserializing value", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {

    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
final IntegerDeserializer keyDeserializer = new IntegerDeserializer();
final MyValueDeserializer myValueDeserializer = new MyValueDeserializer();
final KafkaConsumer<Integer, MyMessage> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props, keyDeserializer, myValueDeserializer);

ConsumerRecords<Integer, MyMessage> records = consumer.poll(1000);
for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, MyMessage> record : records) {

    int kafkaKey = record.key();
    MyMessage kafkaValue = record.value();

    ...
}
```

Comment: final KafkaConsumer<Integer, MyMessage> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props, keyDeserializer, myValueDeserializer);

Comment: Above mentioned it is not as per syntax, Then How can kafka knows about deserializer

Comment: Deserializer is the third argument of the constructor: myValueDeserializer. All of this code was taken from working code, just changed some names.

Comment: Why do you save "isKey" in configure()? Can you explain when configure() and close() should not be empty methods?

Comment: @user1879313 For this code, there is no reason, but the Confluent Serializers, for example, use the boolean field to do different logic on the Schema Registry client and subsequently close the HTTP client in the close() method.

Answer (score 13):

No words, only code

1. Some object, which you sent to Kafka

   ```
   import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
   import lombok.Data;
   import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
   import lombok.ToString;

   @Data
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @ToString
   public class TestDto {

       private String name;
       private String version;

   }
   ```
2. Create Serializer, which will be used by Producer

   ```
   @Slf4j
   public class KafkaValueSerializer implements Serializer<TestDto> {

       private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

       @Override
       public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
       }

       @Override
       public byte[] serialize(String topic, TestDto data) {
           try {
               return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
           } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
               log.error("Unable to serialize object {}", data, e);
               return null;
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void close() {
       }
   }
   ```
3. Of couser, don't foget about Deserialiser for Consumer

   ```
   @Slf4j
   public class KafkaValueDeserializer implements Deserializer<TestDto> {

       private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

       @Override
       public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
       }

       @Override
       public TestDto deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
           try {
               return objectMapper.readValue(new String(data, "UTF-8"), TestDto.class);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               log.error("Unable to deserialize message {}", data, e);
               return null;
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void close() {
       }
   }
   ```
4. Last moment, add serializer/deserializer to *application.yml*

   ```
   spring:
       kafka:
         bootstrap-servers:  192.168.192.168:9092
         producer:
             value-serializer: com.package.service.kafka.KafkaValueSerializer
         consumer:
             group-id: groupId
             value-deserializer: com.package.service.kafka.KafkaValueDeserializer
   ```

That's all. It's not necessary any configuration file or dancing with a tamboirine :)

5. Send

   ```
   KafkaTemplate<String, TestDto> kafkaTemplate;

   TestDto test = new TestDto("test name", "test-version");
   kafkaTemplate.send(topic, testDto);
   ```
6. Listen

   ```
   @KafkaListener(topics = "${ktp-agent.kafka.request-topic}", groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
   public void listen(TestDto message) {

       log.info("Received message '{}' from Kafka.", message.toString());
   }
   ```

Comment: Spring Kafka already has a JSON serializer and deserializer, so probably could remove those from this answer

Comment: Is it possible to send Map<String, TestDto> object through kafka ?

Comment: You can convert Map to Json and send json as example

Comment: Have a question: what if , we dont the incoming message object structure ? then how we can write the deserializer in such instances. ?

Comment: If you don’t know what the message looks like it’s imposible to deserialise.

Answer (score 0):

there is an easier way to do it, basically if you are casting your custom class to bytes in your custom serializer, then you are rebuilding the wheel. kafka already works with bytes.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes;

Bytes bytes = new Bytes(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(<customClass>));
kafkaTemplate.send("topic",bytes);
```

next in your Producter and Consumer configuration

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String,String>(){
Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            "<kafka-server>");
    configProps.put(
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            BytesSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}


@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            "host");
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
            "group-id");
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            BytesDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}
```

finally

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes;


@KafkaListener(topics = "your.topic")
public void getInfoPersona(Bytes message) throws IOException {
    <your-custom-class> customClass = 
    objectMapper.readValue(message.get(), <your-custom-class>.class);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You must create your own serializer which implements the interface `Serializer` (`org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer`) and then set the producer option `key.serializer` / `value.serializer` to it.