# Kafka deserializers based on Topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, deserialization

I have two Kafka topics in my consumer application. How can I configure one topic to use  StringDeserializer (org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer) and other one to use KafkaAvroDeserializer (io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using multiple deserializers for a kafka consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218789/using-multiple-deserializers-for-a-kafka-consumer)

Comment: The best and simplest way to achieve this is to configure and use two consumers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Deserializers are associated with consumers, not topics. So create two of them

Comment: Spring provides a `DelegatingByTopicDeserializer`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DelegatingByTopicDeserializer`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#by-topic

> Starting with version 2.8, the `DelegatingByTopicSerializer` and `DelegatingByTopicDeserializer` allow selection of a serializer/deserializer based on the topic name. Regex `Pattern`s are used to lookup the instance to use.