# How to send a java object as value in producer<K,V>?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, producer-consumer, spark-structured-streaming

Is it possible to send a Java object as the value in a Kafka topic and how do I consume it in spark?

I'm currently doing the apache-spark tutorial and was wondering if it is possible to send something else than a String. The tutorial has this example

```
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, something_string));
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

```
Car car = new Car(brand, year, color);
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, Car>(topic, car));
```

And how do I consume it later in Spark?

At the moment im doing this:

```
String car = brand + "," + year + "," + color;
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, car));
```

Where I put everything in a String with comma-separation.

**Question 2:** At the moment I consume it in this way.

```
Dataset<String> words = df
.selectExpr("CAST (value AS STRING)")
.as(Encoders.STRING());
```

where I get the String:
    `"brand,year,color"`

how do I split it up and put it in separate columns?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't be using comma separated values. JSON would be better if you plan on extracting data within Spark

Answer (score 0):

Your post actually has two questions, you could split them into separate posts. For the 1st question, refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154086/how-to-create-custom-serializer-in-kafka); the central concept is that you have to write a custom serializer.

For the second, the concept is still the same in principal, however you have to write a custom deserializer (decoder) this time on Spark side. Refer [this Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html), it demonstrates how a stream needs to be created from Kafka. However, please not the 'KafkaUtil' class, refer [javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html). It has methods to create streams with Kafka decoder classes.