# Kafka Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am sending an array of JSON by converting it to toString() in Kafka Producer using Spring Boot app, but I am getting following error in Consumer:

> **org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException:
>   Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message**
>       Endpoint handler details:
>       Method [public void com.springboot.service.KafkaReciever.recieveData(com.springboot.model.Student,java.lang.String)
>   throws java.lang.Exception]
>       Bean [com.springboot.service.KafkaReciever@5bb3d42d]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException:
>   Cannot handle message; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException:
>   Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to
>   [com.springboot.model.Student] for GenericMessage
>   [payload=[com.springboot.model.Student@5e40dc31,
>   com.springboot.model.Student@235e68b8], headers={kafka_offset=45,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=myTopic-kafkasender}],
>   failedMessage=GenericMessage
>   [payload=[com.springboot.model.Student@5e40dc31,
>   com.springboot.model.Student@235e68b8], headers={kafka_offset=45,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=myTopic-kafkasender}]

Configuration File:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.boot.server}")
    private String kafkaServer;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.group.id}")
    private String kafkaGroupId;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerConfig() {

         Properties props = new Properties();

         props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
         props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId);
         props.put("message.assembler.buffer.capacity", 33554432);
         props.put("max.tracked.messages.per.partition", 24);
         props.put("exception.on.message.dropped", true);
         props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
         props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
         props.put("segment.deserializer.class", DefaultSegmentDeserializer.class.getName());

         return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(props, null, new StringDeserializer());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> listener = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        listener.setConsumerFactory(consumerConfig());
        return listener;
    }
}
```

Reciever File:

```
@Service
public class KafkaReciever {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaReciever.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.name}", group = "${kafka.consumer.group.id}")
    public void recieveData(@Payload Student student, @Header(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY) String messageKey) throws Exception{
        LOGGER.info("Data - " + student + " recieved");
    }
}
```

POST json:

```
 [{
        "studentId": "Q45678123",
        "firstName": "Anderson",
        "lastName": "John",
        "age": "12",
        "address": {
          "apartment": "apt 123",
          "street": "street Info",
          "state": "state",
          "city": "city",
          "postCode": "12345"
        }
    },
    {
        "studentId": "Q45678123",
        "firstName": "abc",
        "lastName": "xyz",
        "age": "12",
        "address": {
          "apartment": "apt 123",
          "street": "street Info",
          "state": "state",
          "city": "city",
          "postCode": "12345"
        }
    }]
```

I am getting the following consumer output:

```
[com.springboot.model.Student@5e40dc31, com.springboot.model.Student@235e68b8]
```

Comment: Your consumer waits for String (deserializer), but it's receiving a Student. Do you have access to the producer's serializer? You need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154086/how-to-create-custom-serializer-in-kafka

Comment: my Model data is:
public class Student implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 private String studentId;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String age;
 private Address address;

get/set }

Comment: I changed VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG to JsonDeserializer then i got following error:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition myTopic-kafkasender-0 at offset 47
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.springboot.model.Student out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: [B@304eaefb; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: ConsumerFactory<String, String>  please try to user your payload object type like if you class name student then ConsumerFactory<String, Student> 

____________________          props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
 You can user json desrialzer if you need proper ans ping me i will help you

Comment: @harkesh thanks.. adding this getting same error.. but changing in Service as '@Payload List<Student> student ' error solved but data not converted to array of json.

Comment: @VaibhavShelar if you  able to fix it then make a sample project and share it i will update your code and fix issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can not deserialize instance of com.springboot.model.Student out of START_ARRAY

If using a json deserailizer, you have a list, not a single Student

```
@Payload List<Student> student
```

Or if using the string deserailizer, you have a String of JSON and you must parse it manually

```
receiveData(@Payload String student ... ) { 
    JsonNode data = new ObjectMapper().readTree(student); // for example, but should extract ObjectMapper to a field
}
```

Regarding your other output, please see [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: Thanks. I have parsed JSON data in producer and have send it to consumer, after that i am getting proper json data in consumer. just wanted to check, if I am doing this in a correct way or not?

Comment: As long as there are no exceptions, I would say nothing is wrong